# Control the name of a CSV output file

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am outputing a dataframe in a single CSV file as follows:

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
@transform(
         output=Output("/some_path/myoutput_csv"),
         my_input=Input("/some_other_path/myinput")
    )
    def my_compute_function(output, my_input):
         output.write_dataframe(my_input.dataframe().coalesce(1), output_format="csv", options={"header": "true"})
```

My question is how can I modify/control the name of the CSV output?